# Change the site URL for all the actions inside our imported Cloud Power automate Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

We have created a SharePoint test site and and Power Automate cloud flow, where on most of the action we have define the site URL a follow:

[image]

[image]

Now we will export this Flow and import it again then we need to connect it to the Production SharePoint site. so is there  way to automatically change all the site URLs from the test SharePoint site to the new/PROD SharePoint site? or we will have to do this manually on each action?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the adress manually for each action.

Better off using a variable for the site adress next time if you want to use the same Flow for multiple sites or if you need to update the URL in the future without having to manually change it in each action.

Comment: if i use a variable, then i will not get any list inside the "List Name" drop-down, and if i have to define the list as variable, then if i want to update or create a new item inside the list, Power automate will not show the available columns for the items

Answer (score 0):

You have below options to change the SharePoint site URLs when you export/import a Power automate flow:

**1. Importing in same environment (default)**:

You have to manually change all the site URLs to new/PROD SharePoint site for each action.

**2. Importing in different Power Platform environment**:

If you are migrating Power automate flows to different power platform environment, I will suggest you to use the environment variables for SharePoint data source in Power automate flows.

You can find more information about these in below links:

1. [Announcing data source environment variables](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-source-environment-variables/)
2. [Use data source environment variables in canvas apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/environmentvariables#use-data-source-environment-variables-in-canvas-apps)

Comment: now in our case we only have one power platform environment which will hold the Dev & Prod power apps and power automate. so in this case we can not use environment variables ?

Comment: Environment variables are used when moving applications between Power Platform environments. You have to provide values to environment variable during import. If you use same/default environment you cannot set two values (for DEV and PROD) for one environment variable.

Comment: Hi @johnGu, does this answer help you in any way?